# List of Beijing and Standard Chinese vocabulary

Tags: topolect

I am looking for a list that has a 1-on-1 mapping between common Beijing and Standard Chinese vocabulary. For instance, a native from Beijing one would say things like 今儿 and 這兒 which could then be mapped respectively to 今天 and 這裡 in standard chinese.

In lack of a better word I used "Standard Chinese" to refer to the way people in other parts of China speak which (for instance Shanghai) where they do not use erhua when speaking Chinese.

Comment: This is a good question! One complication is that I've observed a three-way split between a/ Beijing Mandarin (lots of 儿化), b/ Mainland Newscaster Mandarin (some 儿化, but only in some words), and c/ Southern and Taiwanese Mandarin (almost no 儿化). E.g., 今儿 in a/ but not b/ or c/, which use 今天; 这儿 in a/ and b/ but not c/, which uses 这里.

Comment: That is correct. I have also noticed that on HSK they sometimes have er hua. Thus, the best would be to have such a list that groups based on frequency based on high or low usage. But I would also be gladly accept any unfiltered 1-on-1 mapping.

Comment: It’s probably easiest just to look through Beijing topolect dictionaries.

Comment: I can contribute several, 掉点儿 raindrops start to drop; 搌布 -> 抹布 dishcloth; 朋友之间称对方父母 咱妈,咱爸 your mother, your father.

Answer (score 1):

北京話 basically has a lot of 兒化音, once in a few words they will 兒化 it. Even as a native Chinese speaker, I'm not quite used to it lol

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you're looking for, but there's a twitter bot called 北京话bot that tweets lots of (what seem to me to be) Beijing colloquialisms.

https://twitter.com/BeijingHua

It gives some explanations of the terms it mentions, in 普通话. Not really a reference but it is quite interesting I think.